# Origin of "Cities of The Red Night"

Tags: william-s-burroughs, cities-of-the-red-night

Does anyone know the source of the names that Burroughs uses in the "Cities of The Red Night" books?  Did he write about it any of his other work?

For reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cities_of_the_Red_Night

The cities' names are: Tamaghis, Ba'dan, Yass-Waddah, Waghdas, Naufana, and Ghadis.

A character in the book says that if you say the names before going to sleep you will receive a dream about the cities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [the Muqaddimah of Ibn Khalud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muqaddimah):

> In the *Ghayah* and other books by practitioners of magic, reference is
>   made to words that should be mentioned on falling asleep so as to cause the dream
>   vision to be about the things one desires. These words are called by (the magicians) "dream words" (*al-halumah*). In the *Ghayah*, Maslamah mentioned a dream word that he called "the dream word of the perfect nature." It consists of saying, upon falling asleep and after obtaining freedom of the inner senses and finding one's way clear (for supernatural perception), the following non-Arabic words: *tamaghis ba'dan yaswadda waghads nawfana ghadis*. The person should then mention what he wants, and the thing he asks for will be shown to him in his sleep.

It's in the [sixth discussion of the first chapter](http://www.muslimphilosophy.com/ik/Muqaddimah/Chapter1/Ch_1_06.htm). The footnotes in the book [tell more](http://www.muslimphilosophy.com/ik/Muqaddimah/Chapter1/Ch_1_06Footnote.htm#310):

> These magical words seem to be Aramaic and may have sounded something like this: *Tmaggesh b'eddan swadh* (?) *waghdhash nawmtha ghadhesh*, "You say your incantations at the time of conversation (?), and the accident of sleep happens."

Google Books has excerpts from a literary analysis, [Mosaic of Juxtaposition: The Narrative Strategy of William S. Burroughs](http://books.google.hu/books?id=TIGkG3D3KRsC), it might contain more details, but I dunno.

Comment: wow! i am amazed.  Thank you very much!